# Performing PostGIS spatial joins with remote host?

Tags: postgis, r, spatial-join, sf

I have approximately 600,000 points that must be joined to ~12 million polygons. This process happens weekly, with the potential to happen daily. The polygon data never changes, and is stored in a remote PostGIS database. The points are currently pushed from R to the remote PostGIS server and ST_DWithin is performed to join polygon attributes to the points. Is there way to **keep my points local** (i.e. within my R environment) and query the **remote polygons**?

The goal is to not let highly confidential information (the points) needlessly be copied to a remote server as a temporary table, if I can help it.

Comment: So if the polygons never change, why don't you copy them to where the sensitive data is?

Comment: Our company won’t let us install Postgres on our local machines, and reading GDB or SHP takes hours to load it in. Also, multiple people need to run the query, so a central database is preferred for that.

Comment: This sort of detail really ought to be in the question, but it makes the question moot, because it's not possible to both use an external database and secure the data.

Comment: Yes, with a foreign data wrapper. There are a couple of gotchas, which i will write up when back at my desk.

Comment: This would be easier to do with Postgres to Postgres foreign data wrappers, due to the ability to allow spatial indexes to be used on the remote machine. It is still possible from R, but will take longer. Why can you not install Postgres locally? The IT departments of companies that prevent people from doing things that lead to productivity enhancements, ie , install Postgres locally, are not really helping. Postgres, last time I looked, was not a tool commonly used by troll farms. What is their "logic"?

Comment: Vince: I'm not sure if it makes the question entirely moot - we would _prefer_ not to write any table (even a temp table) to the remote database, but it isn't out of the question (it is what we do now). As John states, there are foreign data wrappers that may allow for this. John: I'm not in IT, so I can't give you a solid answer. All I can say is that we have **incredibly** strict regulations on our data, so many 'common sense' solutions are not allowed. Speaking of FDW's, you reminded me that there is one for GDAL, and my solution may lay with ogr2ogr.

Comment: My experience of foreign data wrappers is using Postgres as the query engine and connecting to remote data sources, whether that by text, another Postgres box, MongoDB, whatever. Your use case is the other way round, you are working locally, in R, and querying a foreign Postgres box, which you don't want the overhead of having to upload data to. Is this correct?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Why not import the polygons into R, using sf::st_read, then doing the spatial join between points and polygons in R, using sf::st_join?

Comment: That was the initial idea, but the polygons contain 13+M rows, and as such the time/RAM requirements are excessive - I don't have my previous trial times readily available, but it took multiple hours. When the points are all within PostGIS, there is no 'read' overhead and the join operates quickly. We have been able to reduce st_read times by including a query that first finds the point intersections in a larger-aggregate hierarchy with a hierarchical identifier; this process greatly reduces the read time but still leaves us with upwards of an hour to access the fine-resolution polygons.